# AngularJS updating data displayed in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a simple directive:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

function Data(n) {
  this.n = n;
}

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
      new Data(1),
      new Data(2),
      new Data(3)
    ];


  $scope.addNew = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i += 1) {
      $scope.data[i].n *= 10;
    }

    $scope.data.push(new Data(1));
  }

});

app.directive('data', function() {
  return {
          require: 'ngModel',

          template: '<div><span>n using scope: {{n}}</span><br><span>n using model: {{model.n}}</span></div>',

          restrict: 'E',
          link: postLink,
          scope: {},
        };

  function postLink(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
      ngModelController.$render = function() {
          var $viewValue = ngModelController.$viewValue;
          scope.n = $viewValue.n;
          scope.model = $viewValue;
      };
  }
});
```

Plunker link [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/eVt1XWZySkmwMQMDkBxL).

After calling `addNew()` few times I get output:

```
n using scope: 1
n using model: 1000
n using scope: 2
n using model: 2000
n using scope: 3
n using model: 3000
n using scope: 1
n using model: 100
n using scope: 1
n using model: 10
n using scope: 1
n using model: 1
```

I understand why `scope.n` value is not updated (as it is clearly stated in documentation of [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#), but I wonder why `scope.model` value is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you console.log `scope.model` and `scope.n`, you get the following:

`scope.model: Data {n: 1, $$hashKey: "object:21"}`

`scope.n: 1`

I believe the behavior you are seeing is arising because of ng-repeat: angular generates and attaches a $$hashkey to the object, which angular uses to track updates.

The docs say this about $ngModelController's $render method:

> Since ng-model does not do a deep watch, $render() is only invoked if
>   the values of $modelValue and $viewValue are actually different from
>   their previous value. If $modelValue or $viewValue are objects (rather
>   than a string or number) then $render() will not be invoked if you
>   only change a property on the objects.

So it seems that $render is getting invoked for scope.model, but not scope.n, but I don't believe it actually is.  I think it's updating because of the $$hashkey that is getting attached with the object to scope.model.  Because with scope.n you aren't getting the hashkey, it doesn't update.  When angular does a $digest it's going to see that $$hashkey and try to update that binding.

If you take out the $$hashkeys it no longer updates.  We can strip the $$hashkey by transforming the $viewValue before attaching it to scope.model:

`scope.model = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson($viewValue));`
and now if you console.log(scope.model) you get:
`Object {n: 3}`

No more $$hashkey, and the view acts the way you think it would - where $render is not getting invoked.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8wka7wIm2RPoflbFCLK?p=preview)

Comment: I noticed the hashkey on the object too, I was just struggling to put into words what I was seeing. Good answer.

Comment: There is nil in the docs about $$hashkey.  Actually SO was really the only place I've found much in-depth information about it.